# Eclipse Standard Property View - PropertyDescriptor - how to make a property row grey

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

Hello there fellow SO members!

I am writing a plugin for a Eclipse RCP application, and when I am selecting a row from a TreeViewer its properties appear in the Properties View.

Initially I was looking for a way I could make certain properties read-only, and found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562394/read-only-properties-view-for-eclipse-editor). 
Now what I am asking is, how can I make these properties grey? I ask this because I'd like it to be more evident that they are read-only.

Any help/opinions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I look at the `createItem` method from the **PropertySheetViewer** (`org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.PropertySheetViewer`) , it doesn't look too good for you, I guess. The only attributes updated from the TreeItems are the text and the image. There is no coloring done based on any attribute.

Edit: You asked for suggestions too, so I should finish it correctly: If you look at Properties View, then its not more than a simple [view](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_basicext_views.htm) with a two-column table, which is wired to the [SelectionService](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html). So, I guess with a little effort you may implement your own Properties view visualizing the current selection in a proper way.

Comment: So I'd basically have to implement my own PropertySheetPage for such an an endeavor?

Comment: I think its more a PropertySheet which is a "view"-Extension. Then your own View should appear under Window->Show View->Others...